# Control Button Visibility From Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

This Is My Code

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    control.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            s2=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    if (s1==s2){
        button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

}

when trying to control visibility from Firebase above code does not work. If I try same without use of Firebase it works.
Would appreciate any advice

Comment: I think some external information or simple demo corresponding to the code in your question would be expectable to help others understand your situation better. In addition, why it is tagged with `android`  is not very clearly understandable as well, because the description in your question seems not restricted within android development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call this line:

```
if (s1==s2) button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

inside your `onDataChange`:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    control.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            GenericTypeIndicator<String> s = new GenericTypeIndicator<String>() {};
            s2=dataSnapshot.getValue(s);
            if (s1==s2) //you can change this line with "if (s1.equals(s2))"
                button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
}
```

because `addValueEventListener`is asynchronous, so `onDataChange` will be called after `onStart` is finished

Answer (score 1):

Actually addValueEventListener() is an `ASYNC` call, so before the value of `s2` gets assigned it's being compared in your `if(s1==s2)` statement & the value of `s2` is default or null while comparison.

Instead, you can try hiding your button inside your async call itself as

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();
control.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        s2=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        if ( s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s2) )
            button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
//if (s1==s2)  //Remove these lines
    //button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);   
}
```

Comment: Great it worked for you! you can upVote it if it helped you.